# Bottle/TPL/JS: How to return a parameter value from TPL page to python

Tags: javascript, json, bottle

Assume, using bottle/python code which handles a TPL page and spans a HTML page. On that JS is used to process some parameter.
I'm curious how to pass a changed/entered parameter back to the python code for further handling.
This is needed to update parameter with a JSON file on the bottle/python side for later processing.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. What you ask has nothing to do with the Task Parallel Library

Comment: Maybe you are not familiar with the bottle library. tpl stands for a page format definition. Seems you have a different meaning in mind, sorry

Comment: Quite the opposite. Did you actually read what the tag you used said? `task-parallel-library`. This isn't a matter of meaning or interpretation. Did you read what the tag info said? `The Task Parallel Library is part of the .NET Framework since .NET 4.` Using the wrong tag doesn't increase the visibility of your question. It creates noise and annoys the people interested in the tag. It's more likely to attract downvotes than answers

Answer (score 0):

Oops, sometimes you cannot see the forest for the trees ... I had actually already done this elsewhere, using the jquery approach on the tpl/html page with:

```
$.get("/updateStatus?" + device0 + "," + device1);
```

which gives back on python with:

```
@app.route('/updateStatus')
def updateStatus():
    caller = request.fullpath[1:]
    qString = urllib.parse.unquote(request.query_string.strip())
```

and 'qString' hold the passed parameters:

```
"GET /updateStatus?Stecker[61]%20Channel:%20-1,%20Off:%20false%20disabled HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

So, all is fine ... or any other/better solution?